How can an install MicroStack on WSL2 Windows 11Pro
How can an install MicroStack on WSL2 Windows 11Pro. I don’t think I know what I’m doing because the logs are stating Error, Unable to install. It doesn’t seem to be as easy as double clicking the .exe file. Is anyone able to help PLEASE

Thank you for your help. You were right the video was helpful and very easy to follow
